# Merging through fuzzy matching of variables in R

Tags: linux, r, unix

I have two dataframes (x & y) where the IDs are `student_name`, `father_name` and `mother_name`. Because of typographical errors ("n" instead of "m", random white spaces, etc.), I have about 60% of values which are not aligning, though I can eyeball the data and see they should. Is there a way to reduce the level of non-match somehow so that manually editing because at least feasible? The dataframes are have about 700K observations.

R would be best. I know a little bit of python, and some basic unix tools. P.S. I read up on `agrep()`, but don't understand how that can work on actual datasets, especially when the match is over more than one variable.

---

update (data for posted bounty):

[Here](https://gist.github.com/dlebauer/5469662) are two example data frames, `sites_a` and `sites_b`. They could be matched on the numeric columns `lat` and `lon` as well as on the `sitename` column. It would be useful to know how this could be done on a) just `lat` + `lon`, b) `sitename` or c) both.

you can source the file [test_sites.R](https://gist.github.com/dlebauer/5469662/raw/833fa9633ed43e9c435c25743f44ea91a2eb3c63/test_sites.R) which is posted as a gist.

Ideally the answer would end with

```
merge(sites_a, sites_b, by = **magic**)
```

Comment: Can you provide a small subset of your data (or provide us with some fake data)?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Although this was not originally my question, I had a similar issue, have created some sample data, and offered a bounty.

Comment: @David have you tried `merge(sites_a, sites_b, by = c("lon", "lat"))`? In your case, if you want to merge by names, you will have to invest more energy into making the names in both data.frames match (good luck, huh).

Comment: @RomanLuštrik in the example, the coordinates have different levels of precision. Thus, a match on `round(sites_b[,c('lat','lon')],2)` would be close - unless there is a sign error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `agrep` function (part of base R), which does approximate string matching using the [Levenshtein edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) is probably worth trying. Without knowing what your data looks like, I can't really suggest a working solution. But this is a suggestion... It records matches in a separate list (if there are multiple equally good matches, then these are recorded as well). Let's say that your data.frame is called `df`:

```
l <- vector('list',nrow(df))
matches <- list(mother = l,father = l)
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  father_id <- with(df,which(student_name[i] == father_name))
  if(length(father_id) == 1){
    matches[['father']][[i]] <- father_id
  } else {
    old_father_id <- NULL
    ## try to find the total                                                                                                                                 
    for(m in 10:1){ ## m is the maximum distance                                                                                                             
      father_id <- with(df,agrep(student_name[i],father_name,max.dist = m))
      if(length(father_id) == 1 || m == 1){
        ## if we find a unique match or if we are in our last round, then stop                                                                               
        matches[['father']][[i]] <- father_id
        break
      } else if(length(father_id) == 0 && length(old_father_id) > 0) {
        ## if we can't do better than multiple matches, then record them anyway                                                                              
        matches[['father']][[i]] <- old_father_id
        break
      } else if(length(father_id) == 0 && length(old_father_id) == 0) {
        ## if the nearest match is more than 10 different from the current pattern, then stop                                                                
        break
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The code for the `mother_name` would be basically the same. You could even put them together in a loop, but this example is just for the purpose of illustration.

Comment: Thanks, nullglob. Could you please explain using dataframes (x,y) and variables (student_name, etc.) syntax.

Comment: Sorry @user702432, I didn't read your question carefully enough. You and already found `agrep`. I've added a suggestion about how you could use it in conjunction with your data.frame

Answer (score 5):

This takes a list of common column names, matches based on `agrep` of all those columns combined, and then if `all.x` or `all.y` equals TRUE it appends non-matching records filling in missing columns with NA. Unlike `merge`, the column names to match on need to be the same in each data frame. The challenge would seem to be setting the `agrep` options correctly to avoid spurious matches.

```
  agrepMerge <- function(df1, df2, by, all.x = FALSE, all.y = FALSE, 
    ignore.case = FALSE, value = FALSE, max.distance = 0.1, useBytes = FALSE) {

    df1$index <- apply(df1[,by, drop = FALSE], 1, paste, sep = "", collapse = "")
    df2$index <- apply(df2[,by, drop = FALSE], 1, paste, sep = "", collapse = "")

    matches <- lapply(seq_along(df1$index), function(i, ...) {
      agrep(df1$index[i], df2$index, ignore.case = ignore.case, value = value,
            max.distance = max.distance, useBytes = useBytes)
    })

    df1_match <- rep(1:nrow(df1), sapply(matches, length))
    df2_match <- unlist(matches)

    df1_hits <- df1[df1_match,]
    df2_hits <- df2[df2_match,]

    df1_miss <- df1[setdiff(seq_along(df1$index), df1_match),]
    df2_miss <- df2[setdiff(seq_along(df2$index), df2_match),]

    remove_cols <- colnames(df2_hits) %in% colnames(df1_hits)

    df_out <- cbind(df1_hits, df2_hits[,!remove_cols])

    if(all.x) {
      missing_cols <- setdiff(colnames(df_out), colnames(df1_miss))
      df1_miss[missing_cols] <- NA
      df_out <- rbind(df_out, df1_miss)
    }
    if(all.x) {
      missing_cols <- setdiff(colnames(df_out), colnames(df2_miss))
      df2_miss[missing_cols] <- NA
      df_out <- rbind(df_out, df2_miss)
    }
    df_out[,setdiff(colnames(df_out), "index")]
}
```

Comment: Put this into a Gist here: https://gist.github.com/enricoferrero/0e41549d437aeda4d5f2f95116316c00