# Replace the misspelled words

Tags: r, gsub, tm

I have a city column of 25000 rows with lot of misspelled cities in a data frame. The sample looks like below

```
Vishakapatnam, a.p
Vishakapatnam URBAN
Vishakapatnam Distt.
Vishakapatnam
Vishakapatnam
vghjfg"
vgfsgsvsw
Vellore
Vellore
VELLORE
VELLORE
New deklhi
New Dehli
new dehli
NEW DEHI
xxxx

zz
a
1234
5644
3
```

The data contains city with different spelling, numeric, spaces and some random alphabets. I want change the misspelled cities into one name and remove spaces, alphabets with no meaning and numeric. I am trying to do with grep as mentioned in some of the answers here but it is so tedious. Also, I tried with TM package but I could not achieve this. Could some one please share any method which we can do this more efficiently.

Comment: Do you have a list / data set defining *correctly* spelled city names?

Comment: What is the criteria for "alphabets with no meaning"?

Comment: You can remove spaces by `gsub` (e.g. gsub(" ", "", "New Dehli")`. To identify misspelled words I would calculate the Jaccard index (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) or a similar measurments.

Comment: There is no data which tells correct city name. I have to create it manually. And those alphabets are some random one. They do not have any criteria.

Comment: Have a look at: ``maps::world.cities`` which provides a list of 44000 cities. A quick look at it shows that at least *Visakhapatnam* is included. As a start you could try: ``which(cities %in% maps::world.cities)``. Maybe that does help a bit.

Comment: Adding to the suggestion by @Qaswed you may want to look into "fuzzy string matching", http://bigdata-doctor.com/fuzzy-string-matching-survival-skill-tackle-unstructured-information-r/

Comment: Building on @Phann's resource, take a look at this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29360262/find-match-of-two-data-frames-and-rewrite-the-answer-as-data-frame.  You could perhaps use its methodology to match your data frame of names to the world list.